# Extract text value in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I using ElementTree to try and extract a number of values from an XML.

Here is a sample of the xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE playerstats>
<playerstats>
<steamID>76561197960964581</steamID>
<gameName>Team Fortress 2</gameName>
<stats>
    <stat>
        <name>Scout.accum.iNumberOfKills</name>
        <value>1777</value>
    </stat>
    <stat>
        <name>Scout.accum.iPlayTime</name>
        <value>247469</value>
    </stat>
    <stat>
        <name>Scout.accum.iPointCaptures</name>
        <value>641</value>
    </stat>
    <stat>
        <name>Soldier.accum.iNumberOfKills</name>
        <value>1270</value>
    </stat>
    <stat>
        <name>Soldier.accum.iPlayTime</name>
        <value>94649</value>
    </stat>
    <stat>
        <name>Spy.accum.iNumberOfKills</name>
        <value>7489</value>
    </stat>
    <stat>
        <name>Spy.accum.iPlayTime</name>
        <value>1110582</value>
    </stat>
</stats>
</playerstats>
```

There is a lot more, but this is just a sample.

I want to extract and sum all the values relating to "*.accum.iPlayTime", to calculate a total play time. Star implying all classes (e.g. scout, soldier, etc).

My code so far (including some of my attempts):-

```
playerStatsKISA = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=440&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&steamid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=xml')
statsTF2 = playerStatsTF2.read()
theStatsTF2 = ET.fromstring(statsTF2)

totalTimesTF2 = theStatsKISA.findtext("Scout.accum.iPlayTime") # Didn't find anything
print totalTimesKISA

totalTimesTF2 = theStatsKISA.findall("./stats/stat/name") 
for indiv in totalTimesTF2: # Another failed attempt
    print indiv.attrib # didn't extract anything, I gather because the text I'm after is not an attribute but a value?
    if indiv.attrib == 'Scout.accum.iPlayTime':
        print "got it" # would extract value here, but it would be long winded to do this then try and extract the next value I'm actually after.
```

I was going with the idea of acquiring the value from each class then summing it. Though I gather there is probably a away to get all the value in one foul swoop using a * for the TF2 class name, but I was going to do that after I first worked out how to get the value from the tag following one that contained the value I needed.

Hope this made sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`text`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) attribute:

```
root = ET.fromstring(statsTF2)
for stat in root.findall("./stats/stat"):
    if stat.find('name').text.endswith('.accum.iPlayTime'):
        print stat.find('value').text
```

prints (given the xml in the question):

```
247469
94649
1110582
```

---

Using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) with XPath:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(statsTF2)
for text in root.xpath('./stats/stat[name[contains(text(), ".accum.iPlayTime")]]/value/text()'):
    print text
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
totalTime = 0
root = ET.fromstring(statsTF2)
for stat in root.findall("./stats/stat"):
    if stat.find('name').text.endswith('accum.iPlayTime'):
        totalTime+=int(stat.find('value').text)


totalTime
>>> 1452700
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for how to accumulate the values.