# How to get value of element in XML file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Below is the XML file I am trying to read.

```
<annotation>
    <folder>JPEGImages</folder>
    <filename>L00030.png</filename>
    <path>D:\Annotation\Station1\S12508\JPEGImages\L00030.png</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1280</width>
        <height>720</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>bezel</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>plate</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

In the above XML, I am trying to read the value of `object` with `name`, so in this case, it  will be `bezel` and `plate`. I am trying to do this using  `xml` Python package

```
xmlTree = ET.parse("file.xml")

elemList = []
for elem in xmlTree.iter():
    elemList.append(elem.tag)
```

This way I am able to get all the elements but unable to get the value. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: [`elem.text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text)

Comment: The value of an element is in the `text`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19583501/407651

Comment: Note that "`xml` Python package" is ambiguous. There are several XML-related modules in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```py
elemList.append(elem.tag)
```

to this:

```py
elemList.append(elem.text)
```

or this, if you want both:

```py
elemList.append([elem.tag, elem.text])
```

`elem.tag` is the name of the tag, so in `<foo>bar</foo>` it would be `foo`.

`elem.text` is whatever was inside the tag, so in `<foo>bar</foo>` it would be `bar`.

Have a look at [this](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Answer (score 1):

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<annotation>
    <folder>JPEGImages</folder>
    <filename>L00030.png</filename>
    <path>D:\Annotation\Station1\S12508\JPEGImages\L00030.png</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1280</width>
        <height>720</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>bezel</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>plate</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    </object>
</annotation>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
values = [s.find('name').text for s in root.findall('.//object') if s.find('name') is not None]
print(values)
```

output

```
['bezel', 'plate']
```